# Not extracting the full link using index

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to extract the first href link from a website. Just the full link alone.

I am expecting to get `http://www.iana.org/domains/example` as the output but instead I am  getting just `http://www.iana.org/domains/ex`

```
require 'net/http'

source = Net::HTTP.get('www.example.org', '/index.html')

def findhref(page) #returns rest of the html after href
  return page[page.index('href')..-1]
end

def findlink(page)
  text = findhref(page)
  firstquote = text.index('"') #first position of quote
  secondquote = text[firstquote+1..-1].index('"') #2nd quote
  puts text #for debugging
  puts firstquote+1 #for debugging
  puts secondquote #for debugging
  return text[firstquote+1..secondquote]
end




print findlink(source)
```

Comment: Have you considered using Nokogiri gem at all?

Comment: Negative. I'm doing the Udacity's CS101 class building a search engine in Python. I decided to follow that course and build it a Ruby version too.

Comment: Nokogiri is a Ruby gem.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I was just trying to do this exercise as a learning purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) for HTML parsing. The solution to your problem would be as simple as:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('www.example.org/index.html'))

first_anchor = doc.css('a').first
first_href = first_anchor['href']
```